# Rust Command Line History Like In A Terminal

Tags: rust

I have some code in rust that gets the current input in a loop

```rs
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    loop {
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok().expect("Couldn't read line");
        println!("hello {}", input)
    }
}
```

How would I make it put the recent input given into the input when pressing the up arrow like in a terminal

Terminal example:

```
>> echo "hello"
hello
>> echo "hello" [pressed up arrow]
hello
```

How I want it:

```
>> bucket
hello bucket
>> bucket [pressed up arrow]
hello bucket
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you might be interested in checking out https://github.com/fdehau/tui-rs
Basically you'll not read a line from stdin but react to the key event. Which, if you want to keep the regular input behaviour, makes things a bit more complicated than I can quickly cobble together for an SO answer. Basically regular keypresses would need to append to the output and arrow key would have to clear that typed input and replace it with the previous command. So you'll need to do some cursor manipulation, too. A lower-level lib for that, is https://crates.io/crates/ncurses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the keyword you are looking for might be "readline", which is the GNU library used to implement this functionality in many applications. For Rust, there is for instance [rustyline](https://docs.rs/rustyline/8.2.0/rustyline/), among others.